# How do I make a custom lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, battery-life, clock, lock-screen

I would like to display the time as an analog clock on my lock screen, and I would like to show my battery percentage as a large loading bar stretching across my screen. Can I design a custom lock screen for Windows 10? Is there some sort of software or lock screen out there similarly to the extensions and themes offered in the Google Chrome Web Store? Or is this something that I would have to program and design myself? Would a lock screen like this also be possible on Linux?

I had already tried googling these keywords "unique lock screen, live lock screen, live wallpaper, custom lock screen, how to display battery percentage/life on lock screen", and other search terms but I didn't find anything too compelling. Anyways, I'd appreciate any guidance you could give me.

Comment: that doesn't sound right about your battery, if anything Linux mint should be using less battery than windows

Comment: Consider cleaning up the story portion in your question and getting right to the point keeping only the detail that's applicable to what you are requesting.

Comment: Hi Keith M. I read online that Linux uses more battery power because the drivers are optimized for Windows rather than Linux.

Comment: Hi McDonald's. I'll clean up then but I didn't find anything on Google so I wasn't sure if anyone knew about this. I also didn't want people replying to tell me that no such feature existed or that I can just change the lock screen image. I'm trying to do more than simply change the lock screen background image. I want a dynamic lock screen that can show me battery life and time in a fancy way.

Comment: I've used https://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/ in the past on older versions of Windows that does this. It used to be free so you might check it out. Asking for 3rd party solutions is off-topic here I believe so don't forget about the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) community.

Comment: @McDonald's Thanks so much. If I could upvote your comment, I would but that's a great starting point for me. I didn't even know there was a Software Recommendations community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are asking how to personalize your lock screen:

> To tweak your lock screen to your liking, select the **Start** 
>   button, then select **Settings**  > **Personalization**  > **Lock
>   screen** . Try changing the background to a favorite photo or slide
>   show, or choose any combination of detailed and quick status
>   notifications to show you upcoming calendar events, social network
>   updates, and other app and system notifications.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17185/windows-10-lock-screen
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2437429&seqNum=6

If the built in apps don't do what you want (which they don't) then download and install a lock screen compatible app that does display the info you want, in the way you want, and add it to your lock screen.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am not looking to change the background image. I want to customize the lock screen and add battery percentage displays as well as clock display customization.

Comment: There is a mechanic within Windows to indicate you want to display the battery indicator on the lock screen.  What you do indeed want is to change the background image of the lock screen.  While I do not agree that the author of this answer should have even made the comment about how you should have done a google search before asking this question, nor do I agree a link-only answer is helpful, changing the image on the lock screen is indeed what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, it is what you want to do. If you want the clock and battery indicator to look different you have to download and install a lock screen compatible app and add it to your lock screen. The built in ones do not do what you want. Adding and choosing apps on your lock screen is done at the same spot as changing the background. Sorry, didn't include a smiley face after my Google fu comment, but c'mon really?

Comment: I didn't know what to search for so I didn't see anything about lock screen apps but that is what I want. Thanks for editing the answer and thank you for all of the comments. Also that downvote did not come from me. :P

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the lazy answer but i am not yet able to write comments. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2270527/5393353)
question from stack overflow may provide an answer to your question.

Additional bit of information:
The UI of an operating system is generally called its shell. It is possible to change the shell of windows but i doubt it would be a very easy task. gl

Comment: no comment on why it got a downvote? '-_-

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't downvote you but that is a bit more complex than I had wanted since I only wanted a custom lock screen but that additional tidbit of information helps!